# System.FormatException occured in mscorlib.dll while reading I/O stream for loading games on XNA

Tags: c#, io, xna

First of here is the code:

```
            if (Global.SaveDevice.FileExists(Global.containerName, Global.Challenges))
        {
            Global.SaveDevice.Load(
                Global.containerName,
                Global.Challenges,
                stream =>
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        Challenges.CompleteCount = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.Colorist = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ConsecutiveI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ConsecutiveII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ConsecutiveIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ConsecutiveIV = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.CountDownWizardI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.CountDownWizardII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.CountDownWizardIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.MultiplierI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.MultiplierII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.MultiplierIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.MultiplierIV = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.OneUpI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.OneUpII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.OneUpIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.OneUpIV = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.PongWizardI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.PongWizardII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.PongWizardIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ScoreI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ScoreII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ScoreIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ScoreIV = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.ScoreV = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.StarShifterWizardI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.StarShifterWizardII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                        Challenges.StarShifterWizardIII = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                });
```

I get a "System.FormatException occured in mscorlib.dll" for line 12 ( Challenges.ConsecutiveI = bool.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); ) and if I comment it out I also receive it for the following lines when parsing but I don't get the exception in the first two lines of parsing. What I'm trying to do here is load a bunch of stuff using Nick Gravelyn's EasyStorage sample and its worked fine for saving objects in different classes with different errr I think they a called "sub containers" such as Global.Challenges and then Global.Options ect but yeah I'm stumped as to whats the source of the problem.

Here is the last two lines of the call stack as well:

> GameStateManagementSample.exe!GameStateManagement.ChallengesScreen..ctor.AnonymousMethod__0(System.IO.Stream stream) Line 42 + 0x6 bytes    C#
>       EasyStorage.dll!EasyStorage.SaveDevice.Load(string containerName, string fileName, EasyStorage.FileAction loadAction) Line 75 + 0x7 bytes   C#

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your code for serializing your data? You might be saving your data in a different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one of the lines in the file doesn't say "True" or "False".

Comment: Hmm Your'e right I checked its output and two separate saves from different classes were merging into one sub container and since the first two were the same variable types it didn't cause the exception there but it did later on. All fixed now, thank you!